# Download notification does not disappear after application installation in Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am automatically downloading new versions of my app (private app outside Google play store) using `downloadManager.addCompletedDownload()` with the last parameter `showNotification = true`.

On previous android version, when the new application download is complete, a notification pops up and when the new application is installed, the notification disappears. This behaviour has changed with 4.2.2 on Nexus 7 since the notification remains even when the app is installed, until the Nexus 7 is switched off.

I did not find any workaround yet.